# Dict Manipulation

Tags: python, file, python-2.7, dictionary

I have to compare two files (`dict`) and find the value of `key1` and `key2` from the second `dict` with `value` and write the `key value` to third file. I can read and write the files well. I am stuck with `key` and `value` comparison process. Files have more than two columns but we are interested in only col[0] and col[1].

```
file 1: Key1 and key2 are part of key

Key1    Key2
0         1
2         4
3         1
4         0

file 2: 

    value  key
    3416   0
    4562   1
    3566   2
    7843   3
    2341   4
```

I check if `key1` and `key2` are present in `Key` from file 2 (which they are definitely present) and print the corresponding `value as value1 value2 in col[0] col[1]`.

```
from collections import defaultdict

d1 = {}
d2 = {}

with open('file1.txt', 'r') as file1:
    for row in file1:
            cols = row.split()
            key1 = cols[0]
            key2 = cols[1]
            #print key1, key2

with open('file2.txt', 'r') as file2:
    for row in file2:
            cols = row.split()
            value = cols[0]
            #print value

for key in d1, value in d2:
    d1[key1] = d2[value]
    d1[key2] = d2[value]
    print d1[key1], d1[key2] 



Error:
        KTraceback (most recent call last):
      File "file_merge.py", line 20, in <module>
        d1[key1] = d2[value]
    KeyError: '3545'

    3545 is one of the value in file 2
```

Comment: can you add the complete ERROR ?

Comment: How do you populate `d2`? How is `key` for `file2.txt` related to `key1` and `key2` for `file1.txt`? i.e, if `key1 == "abc"` and `key2 == "def"`, what is the value for the `key`?

Comment: Included details about key and value.

Comment: All the answers below seem to be correct but when real data file input is given they all seem to be showing same error that i am having in my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't insert any data into `d2`. I suppose it should be like this:

```
d2 = {}

with open('file2.txt', 'r') as file2:
    for row in file2:
        cols = row.strip().split()
        d2[cols[1]] = cols[0]

with open('file1.txt', 'r') as file1:
    for row in file1:
        cols = row.strip().split()
        print ("%s\t%s" % (d2[cols[0]], d2[cols[1]]))
```

On your data it gives:

```
3416    4562
3566    2341
7843    4562
2341    3416
```

Comment: This takes only the `first Key` but not the values

Comment: @SitzBlogz I don't know your initial intention, it's unclear from the code. In your question you have only two columns in file2.txt, it's up to you to modify code properly to support your actual data.

Comment: I did explain: one file has keys in first 2 columns and file 2 also has 2 columns with one column col[0] as value and col[1] as key (same those from file1). The corresponding values of key1 and key2 are to be printed.

Comment: @SitzBlogz check the answer. And actually you didn't explain: you should have provided expected output for your input.

Comment: `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "m_f.py", line 14, in <module>
    print ("%s\t%s\n" % (d2[cols[0]], d2[cols[1]]))
KeyError: '384'`  384 is the first value in file2 col[1]

Comment: That means you don't have the key 384 in file2.txt

Comment: I definitely have that key in both files.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/60396/discussion-between-anton-savin-and-sitz-blogz).

Answer (score 1):

```
def yield_key_from_file1():
    with open("file1.txt") as fp:
        for line in fp:
            k1, k2 = line.split()
            yield k1.strip()
            yield k2.strip()

def get_dict_from_file2():
    data = {}
    with open("file2.txt") as fp:
        for line in fp:
            value, key = line.split()
            data[key.strip()] = value.strip()
    return data

def write_dict_to_file3(data):
    with open("file3.txt", 'w') as fp:
        for key, value in data.iteritems():
            line = "{0} {1}\n".format(key, value)
            fp.write(line)

def main():
    keys = set(yield_key_from_file1())
    print("f1_keys", keys)
    f2_dict = get_dict_from_file2()
    print("f2_dict", f2_dict)
    f3_dict = dict(
        (key, f2_dict[key]) for key in keys if key in f2_dict
    )
    print("f3_dict", f3_dict)
    write_dict_to_file3(f3_dict)

if __name__ == '__main__':
   main()
```

Comment: `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "m_f.py", line 36, in <module>
    main()
  File "m_f.py", line 25, in main
    keys = set(yield_key_from_file1())
  File "m_f.py", line 6, in yield_key_from_file1
    k1, k2 = line.split()
ValueError: too many values to unpack`

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if your are looking for something like this. Your question is not completely clear to me ..

```
listofkey1 = []
listofkey2 = []
mydict = {}

with open('file1.txt', 'r') as file1:
    for row in file1:
            cols = row.split()
            listofkey1.append(cols[0])
            listofkey2.append(cols[1])


with open('file2.txt', 'r') as file2:
    for row in file2:
            cols = row.split()
            mydict[(cols[1])] = cols[0]
            #print mydict 

for key1, key2 in  zip(listofkey1, listofkey2):
    print mydict[key1], mydict[key2]
```

You get this output from above code:

```
3416 4562
3566 2341
7843 4562 
2341 3416
```

The above are corresponding values for key1 and key2 in your file1.txt

Comment: `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "m_f.py", line 21, in <module>
    print mydict[key1], mydict[key2]
KeyError: '384'` 384 is the first key in file1 which is also present in file2 as key.

Comment: The output is correct what you are getting but i am getting error.

Comment: Do you get exception ?

Comment: No exceptions that i see